# How to setting textbox in userform for fractional value?

Tags: vba, excel, textbox, userform

I have two problems about the fraction number in user form textbox.

1. How to retrieve a value from excel sheet and show it in the textbox with fraction. For example 0.5(sheet) will be shown as 1/2 (textbox). not all values are fraction, there are also value for integer

This is the code to retrieve the value from the sheet

```
Set ctlTXT = Me.SizeFrame.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
ctlTXT.name = "OD" & counter
ctlTXT.value = Sheet2.Range("P" & findstart + counter - 1).value
ctlTXT.Left = 72
ctlTXT.Height = 15: ctlTXT.Width = 54
ctlTXT.Top = 45 + ((counter - 1) * 17 + 2)
```

2. How to return the **fractional value** inserted in the user form textbox using case select statement. From the code below, there is no value return when 1/2 or 3/4 inserted in textbox.

This is the code for case select

```
Select Case X
    Case "1 / 2"
        Y = 15
    Case "3 / 4"
        Y = 20
    Case 2
        Y = 40
End Select
```

Both of these code is not a complete code.

Comment: Could you show more code to put in context, particularly where the X in your `Select Case X` is coming from?

Comment: X is the value inserted in the textbox, Y is the value that will be returned into the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, you can try

```
ctlTXT.Value = WorksheetFunction.Text(Sheet2.Range("P" & findstart + counter - 1).Value, "#?/?")
```

Comment: If value in Sheet2.Range("P" & findstart + counter - 1) is say 0.5, it will be displayed in textbox as 1/2.

Comment: but it does not show as 1/2 in textbox. The value in the sheet is 0.5

Comment: It does when I checked it. See it here  https://www.dropbox.com/s/13d2chvmmgxih0m/DecimalToFraction.xlsm?dl=0